# select n top ranked names from a python list based on a rank-list

Tags: python, list

I have a sorted python list of ranks and a corresponding list of names.
How do I get all the top 5 names in the order of the rank from the python list rank?

```
rank: [ 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1]
names:  ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

desired output:

```
['X', 'Y', 'A', 'B', 'D']
```

I got this.. but does not limit to top 5

```
[ j for (i,j) in zip(rank, names) if i <= 2 ]
```

Comment: Are you sure about the desired output? Or maybe please explain better the logic behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with `zip`:

```
In [244]: [x for _, x in sorted(zip(rank, names))][:5]
Out[244]: ['A', 'B', 'D', 'Y', 'X']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort twice to get the required result (Itemgtter is to extract the value at index 0)-

```
from operator import itemgetter
result = list(map(itemgetter(0),sorted(sorted(zip(names,rank),key=lambda x:x[1])[:5],key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)))
print(result ) # ['X', 'Y', 'A', 'B', 'D']
```